# builtins.KeyError: 'x' при объединении датафреймов в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, исключения

Пишу программу для собственных целей и на определённом этапе возникла необходимость научиться объединять четыре датафрейма из созданных ранее csv-файлов на основании одного столбца (значения в нём в разных файлах идут в разном порядке, но в целом совпадают).

Файлы: «RP.csv», «TF.csv», «ATR.csv» и «BF.csv».

Датафреймы из указанных файлов:

```
tf = pd.read_csv('TFhorsesDB.csv', names=['Horse', 'OddsTF'])
rp = pd.read_csv('RPhorsesDB.csv', names=['Date', 'Course', 'Time', 'Horse', 'OddsRP'])
atr = pd.read_csv('ATRhorsesDB.csv', names=['Horse', 'OddsATR'])
bf = pd.read_csv('BFhorsesDB.csv', names=['Horse', 'OddsBF'])
```

Столбец, на основании которого нужно объединить данные – “Horse”.

Датафрейм, на основании которого должно происходить объединение – «rp».

Задав соответствующий вопрос ранее, получил ответ с кодом:

```
res1 = rp.assign(x=rp['Horse'].str.lower().str.replace(r'\W','')).merge(tf.assign(x=tf['Horse'].str.lower().str.replace(r'\W','')).drop('Horse',1),on='x').drop('x', axis=1)
```

Насколько я понял данную строку (не имея опыта в программировании и лишь постигая его) при её выполнении создаётся столбец «х» в датафрейме “rp”, значения в котором приводятся к формату прописных букв без пробелов и иных знаков (не букв и не цифр); таким же образом создаётся столбец в датафрейме «tf», они объединяются, после удаляются исходные столбцы «Horse».

Но, при попытке таким же образом присоединить данные из других датафреймов («atr» и «bf») возбуждается исключение: builtins.KeyError: 'x' в модуле "generic.py".

Вот часть кода, где возникает ошибка:

```
res1.merge(atr.assign(x=atr['Horse'].str.lower().str.replace(r'\W','')).drop('Horse',1),on='x').drop('x', axis=1)
res1.merge(bf.assign(x=bf['Horse'].str.lower().str.replace(r'\W','')).drop('Horse',1),on='x').drop('x', axis=1)
```

Насколько я понял из описания функции в «generic.py», проблема в несоответствии ключа, по которому объединяются последующие датафреймы, но никак не могу разобраться, что конкретно не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> KeyError: 'x'

говорит о том, что Pandas не может найти столбца с именем `x`.

Проблема вызвана преждевременным удалением нормализованного столбца `x`.

Попробуйте так:

```
def norm(ser):
    return ser.str.lower().str.replace(r'\W','')

res = (rp.assign(x=norm(rp['Horse']))
         .merge(tf.assign(x=norm(tf['Horse'])).drop('Horse',1), on='x')
         .merge(atr.assign(x=norm(atr['Horse'])).drop('Horse',1), on='x')
         .merge(bf.assign(x=norm(bf['Horse'])).drop('Horse',1), on='x')
         .drop('x', axis=1)  # удаляем технический столбец в самом конце (когда он уже не нужен)
       )
```